# Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0 not found by visual studio 2015?

Tags: 64-bit, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

**Visual Studio 2015**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Microsoft .NET Framework -Version 4.7.03056

**SQL SERVER 2017**

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)

Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017

Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10

Home Single Language 10.0  (Build 17134: )

Unable to add data connection.

**Error As below**

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you do still need it or not, but I had similar setup. So here it goes.

Step 1. Install SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992

Outcome: Still didn't work. Apparently some of the packages are moved to NuGet starting from SQL Server 2017

==============================================================================

Step 2. Install Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects through NuGet

[Under your solution name -> reference -> right click -> manage NuGet packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOvLO.png)

Outcome: Still didn't work.

=============================================================================

Step 3 install SQL Server Data Tools for visual studio 2015

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905068/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version

Outcome: Some options are disappeared due to compatibility issues between MVC version and ASP.Net version

=============================================================================

Step 4:

Reference 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437266/ado-net-entity-data-model-missing-visual-studio-2015-community

Reference 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933767/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-from-visual-studio-2012-professional

Outcome: Using reference 2 and repair it, it fixed my problem :)

===============================================================================

To sum it up, I think step 4 is more for fixing my problem, you might be able to have it working with steps 1,2 and 3.

Hope it fixes your problem.